# How to highlight a word on mouseover in text in a React app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How to highlight a word on mouseover in text in a React app

```
const text = data[data.length - 1] !== undefined ? data[data.length - 1].taskText : null;

 const [hilightWord, setHilightWord] = useState(false);

  const hightlight = (text, hilightWord) => {
    if (!hilightWord) return text;

    const regex = new RegExp(`(${hilightWord})`, "gi");

    return text.split(regex).map((substring, i) => {
      return (
        <span className={styles.highlight} key={i}>
          {substring}
        </span>
      );
    });
  };


<p className={styles.text} onMouseMove={() => setHilightWord(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHilightWord(false)}>{hightlight(text, hilightWord)}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly your requirement, but it seems like you want the text to be highlighted on `mouseover`. A really easy way to achieve this is by using **CSS `:hover` selector** (this wont even require any JavaScript).

Implementation:

```js
return (
   <span className="word" key={i}>
      {substring}
   </span>
);
```

CSS:

```css
.word:hover{
   background-color: #FFFF00;
  /*Add your highlight styles*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your styles variable add this.

```js
const styles = {
  ....
  highlight: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
    }
  }
  ....
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `spit()` your sentence, then wrap it in some DOM element (`em` for example), then you can use some CSS to set a `:hover` color on the words.

Small example:

```js
const Highlight = ({ text }) => {
    const splitted = text.split(' ');
    return splitted.reduce((p, c) => ([ ...p, ' ', <em>{c}</em> ]), []);
}

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Highlight Example'}</h1>
            <Highlight text={'Hello world! Hover me to highlight!'} />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
em { font-style: unset; }
em:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```